# ZFS: Handling massive no. of concurrent RW operations and failover

Tags: load-balancing, replication, failover, zfsonlinux, cloud-scale

I have a single ZFS/Linux instance with a file that can grow to those crazy sizes supported by ZFS.

A large number of concurrent users need to read/write from/to this file over the public inter net. How do I load-balance this massive file-access load across a pool of ZFS/Linux instances with identical file-system data and meta-data?

Also - While ZFS can self-heal from minor bit-rot, how can failover to a replicated set of ZFS/Linux instances in case of a total hardware failure be implemented?

Nobody seems to be talking about replicas, failovers, and load-balancing in context of ZFS. Or maybe, I haven't trawled the Internet long enough.

Comment: If you want to hear my opinion, the application is just trash and poorly designed. What kind of an application depends on a single gigantic file?!

Comment: @paladin Fine, ignore for a moment the case of a single gigantic file. How about a large no. of small files spread across various directories in the ZFS instance? File-locking for concurrent access is also taken care of. How do I now address failover and load-balancing for this ZFS instance?

Comment: This entire question is missing lots of details and concrete concepts. For example, does "instances" refer to disks, zpools or whole server nodes? How does "read/write" happen, over NFS, SMB or HTTP (like WebDAV)?

Comment: ZFS is designed as a single-host storage solution, so (cross-node) replication, failover, clustering and other high-availability features are never a concern of ZFS. Chances are you'll have to handle all of these at the application level, which is why I asked about file protocol in the first place. If you really need that kind of availability that a single enterprise-grade server can't provide, you should look into things like Ceph, but be warned about their performance.

Comment: Just came to my mind that Lustre is one of those better distributed filesystems that can use ZFS as backend. I heard quite a few fellow universities and research institutes using Lustre for their supercomputing cluster, though I myself have never touched a Lustre cluster so this is only a hint.

Comment: I think there's a big XY problem here. "_A large number of concurrent users need to read/write from/to this file over the public inter net._" tells me "web services backed by a database" not "gigantic shared file". Then the issue of what type of database (SQL or NoSQL) and what kind of replication/load balancing comes into play, but it's very unlikely that this would be a FS problem.

Comment: @jcaron I can assure you it's not an XY problem here. You can 100% trust me when I say that I just cannot use any (SQL or NoSQL) database mainly because of other application constraints

Comment: @iBug _'For example, does "instances" refer to disks, zpools or whole server nodes?'_  The whole server -- or rather, the entity that provides access to the data using `fread()` and `fwrite()`, completely insulating the application from even knowing if it's a ZFS or an ext4 that's storing the file.

Comment: @iBug  _'How does "read/write" happen, over NFS, SMB or HTTP (like WebDAV)?'_


Using the IP address of the server hosting ZFS. I'm not sure if NFS or SMB can scale w.r.t. to remote user requests for the file data

Answer (score 6):

Neither ZFS nor BTRFS are intended to be replicated between instances in real time. You need to look into the specific category of Distribute File Systems. The Wikipedia page [Comparison of distributed file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_distributed_file_systems) gives a good starting list.

Comment: When you create a BTRFS RAID1 array with 2 volumes, you can later add 2 more volumes and increase RAID1 to RAID1c4, which will create 4 complete copies of each file, 1 copy per volume. This works all online and doesn't need much administrative work. What do you mean with real time?

Comment: @paladin the main words are `between instances`.

Comment: @AlexD It's not even clear what "instances" refers to. Disks? Pools? Server nodes? Without that we can only speculate and can't work out an answer.

Comment: @iBug the question mentions `ZFS/Linux instances`, `failover to a replicated set of ZFS/Linux instances in case of a total hardware failure`.

Comment: @iBug I've clarified it now that I mean the entity in ZFS that abstracts away all disks, zpools and the ZFS-specific what-have-yous that a C application program will never want to care to know about when using `fread` or `fwrite`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about ZFS "RAID" modes, but BTRFS "RAID" modes are unique and special and grant great flexibility, inbuilt-load-balancing and redundancy.

For example BTRFS RAID1 doesn't work on the block level, but on the filesystem level. When you create a BTRFS RAID1 with 4 disks, the RAID mode says that every file is at least stored on 2 different disks (on filesystem level). So for example you have disks A, B, C and D, now you save your file TESTFILE onto your BTRFS RAID1, TESTFILE is then saved on 2 of the 4 drives as a complete copy. This gives you an performance advantage, as only 2 drives really need to do work in that moment, same goes for reading files.

With BTRFS you can just add/remove disks to/from the "RAID"-array without any problems. You can replicate entire BTRFS filesystems or just the subvolume parts of filesystems using the `send`/`receive` commands (useful for backups).

I really don't know much about ZFS but I could imagine that it has also such feature like BTRFS. If it has not such feature, I would replace it with BTRFS.

Comment: It is faster to read a file in parallel from 4 drives than from 2, so the words "same goes for reading files" are incorrect.

Comment: @AlexD If only that happens with BTRFS, which load-balances read by PID. Interesting approach though often not the most performant.

Comment: @iBug, do I understand correctly that BTRFS doesn't benefit from striping and reads only from one stripe?

Comment: @AlexD "Striping" is like RAID 0. My previous comment applies to BTRFS implementation of RAID 1 or mirroring. Also if you have multiple processes working together you do get the benefit.

Comment: Imagine you have 4 users, each user is accesing different files from the same BTRFS filesystem. The filesystem is a RAID1 (BTRFS style) of 4 volumes. The 4 different files are stored across the RAID1, each file has a double on another volume. Volume A has File1 and File2, volume B has File2 and File3, volume C has File3 and File4 and volume D has File4 and File1. User A access File1, user B access File2, user C access File3, user D access File4 --> volume A serves File1 to user A, volume B serves File2 to user B, volume C serves File3 to user C, volume C serves File4 to user D, independently.

Comment: @paladin This has to be the perfect case which AFAIK BTRFS doesn't provide direct API to achieve. And in the long run this isn't something you can rely on, chances are things mix up very quickly.

Comment: @iBug so, BTRFS fails to utilize the bandwidth of multiple devices in the simple sequential read of a single file by a single process? Is that correct?

Comment: As far as I know, BTRFS only uses to read from a single volume, even in RAID1. But the developers are considering to add this as optional feature in future releases. In my opinion this is not a failure but another use case, which is higher redundancy and lower latency.

Comment: @AlexD Precisely.